# How to make tablix expand towards the left?

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services

I have a tablix, one with dynamic columns. The order is fine ("total" shows up last) but the problem is that, for scanning purposes, the last column needs to always be aligned right and any additional columns have to be to the left of that origin point. **How to accomplish this?**

I've tried setting the "Direction" of the column to RTL and tried putting another object on the right of the tablix but that just gets pushed to the right for every extra column. **Is there some sort of anchor property I'm missing or something that'll keep the tablix from growing on the right side?**

Answer (score 0):

There aren't any properties that allow you to dynamically change the width of columns or the position of tables etc. As a table grouping grows, it pushes other elements out of the way. First thing to try is put both of the tables in a rectangle. This can help keep them in position.
Another option is to use visibility to change where your values appear, while maintaining the same underlying layout. Depending on the specifics of how you're trying to lay things out, this may be difficult to use for your purposes.

Comment: So tables only expand on the right side and never the left?

Comment: Correct, they never expand left or up.